# Why is my link messed up?

Tags: support, hyperlinks, markdown

[What is the best planetary orbit around a black hole in order to support life?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/22795/what-is-the-best-planetary-orbit-around-a-black-hole-in-order-to-support-life)

My comment has a wikipedia link, but the close-square-bracket is not being taken and the link runs on to the whole thing.

Answer (score 5):

You wrote :

> See Greg Egan's novel
>   [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incandescence_(novel)](Incandescence)

You should have written

> See Greg Egan's novel [Incandescence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incandescence_(novel))

Answer (score 3):

Samuel is correct. The syntax for Markdown links is: `[link text](full link URL)`.

You wrote `[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incandescence_(novel)](Incandescence)` or in other words, `[full link URL](link text)`. This is not a valid Markdown link, so the default behavior of making a link out of what appears to be a URL probably kicked in. With unusual characters in the URL, that can easily backfire.